# Which was the first war in which photography was employed?

Tags: military, war, photography

Undoubtedly photography has greatly changed public perception of war; but there is no *clear point* in which photography began to be used—whether for documenting war or anything else. So I’m left wondering, in which war was photography first used to document?

Comment: Why is this tagged United-States? Are you specifically looking for instances of wars the USA were involved in? Or did you pre-tag it in reference to your answer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_photography. I thought we were trying to complement common historical references, not duplicate them.

Comment: The closing of the question was absolutely unfair. The theme is NOT covered by Wikipedia.

Comment: By asking "which war was photography first used to document?" do you mean documenting all sides of the conflict, from beginning to end, at the front and at home, in battle and in boredom and in propaganda and in medicine and in transport and in weaponry and in tactics and in battlefields and in politicians and in rallies and in uniforms, etc.? To what extent do you infer such documentation? Would a snapshot of a soldier cleaning a weapon count as documentation of such a war? I'm unclear as the the level and detail of usage of photography in documenting a war is being sought here.

Comment: The answer can not be easily answered by looking up the relevant topic on Wikipedia! It is an obvious lie. There were wars before Mexican war and after the daggerotype invention. And photography was used in some of them.

Comment: The question contains no research, and the question *provides no explanation why Wikipedia does not answer the question.* If someone were to move the comments into the question, then the re-open would be much easier to support.

Comment: related but not duplicate : https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2671/what-was-the-first-major-historical-event-to-be-photographed/64117

Comment: @MCW there are many photos up to ten years earlier than the "first" photos of the wiki article. As for the earliest photos, the article is utterly unsufficient.

Comment: @KerryL Author means what he says: "In which war was photography first used to document" He puts no limit to what detail of the war was documented.

Answer (score 28):

There is an article on this very subject. (http://militaryhistorynow.com/2012/06/12/how-early-photographers-captured-historys-first-images-of-war/).  But we don't need to believe there were no other war photos.

Since daguerreotype invention in 1839 there were the following wars in which Europeans participated:

source: [list of wars from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_1800%E2%80%9399#1840.E2.80.931849)

- Russian Conquest of Bukhara - from 1842
- Franco-Moroccan War - 1844
- Franco-Tahitian War - from 1844
- First Anglo-Sikh War - 1845-46
- Hutt Valley Campaign - 1846 (Britain) For that we can see the photo of the governor George Grey who initiated the war

[image]

- Galician slaughter - 1846 (Austria)
- Dutch intervention in Northern Bali 1846
- Seventh Xhosa War - 1846-47 (Britain)
- Second Carlist War - 1846-49 (Spain)
- Sonderbund War - 1847 (Swiss)

There are photos from the next one - Mexican war - 1848

[image]

First acknowledged war photographer, according to the article mentioned, is Carol Popp de Szathmari, Hungarian.
After him there started French photographer Ernest Eduard de Caranza and
British photographer Roger Fenton, Crimean war http://www.allworldwars.com/Crimean-War-Photographs-by-Roger-Fenton-1855.html

I have found an even earlier war photographer. "John McCosh, a surgeon in the Bengal Army, is considered by some historians to be the first war photographer known by name. He produced a series of photographs documenting the Second Anglo-Sikh War, from 1848–49". There was an exhibition about him in London in 2009.

[image]

There is one English photo of Afghan soldiers of 1843, but it is an inscenated one, they are really actors.
[image]

There is a picture of New Hampshire Volunteer Militia on parade in 1846. I have found more photos of soldiers from 1846, but the date was unsure for them. This seems to be the oldest military photo with the known year.

[image]

The problem is that even if we find photos of earlier times, we most probably won't recognize them as pure photos, for they were of very low quality and were drawn on for improvement of the image quality.

Answer (score 27):

Cameras saw limited use in the Mexican War and in Britain's Crimean War, but their first significant use came during the American Civil War.

Matthew Brady and his skilled assistants, among them Alexander Gardner and Timothy O'Sullivan, photographed not only the generals and their foot soldiers but also the battlefields strewn with the human debris of death—forever changing the way we view war.

During the Civil War, however, photography was used only for documenting the *remains* of war; battlefields, for instance, and troops camping, NOT actual action. The Franco-Prussian War was the first in which an actual ongoing battle was photographed.

[image]

Comment: Why "Britain's Crimean war"? Britain was a part of the coalition (France, Turkey and Sardinia).

Comment: Which war is that photo from?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen searching "franco prussian war photographs" brings this photo up on Google, however I cannot find any reliable sources

Comment: @IlmariKaronen A full resolution image can be found at the Wikipedia page: [Prussian victory parade through Paris in 1871 after the Franco-Prussian War](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:S95francoprussian.jpg)

Comment: Indeed, it's looks like a parade rather than "an actual ongoing battle". This answer is interesting but would be made much more helpful if it included sources.

Comment: The top left corner shows a fountain inside a park. So possibly near the **Place de la Concorde**.